# How to convert from decimal to date in scala select?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a column datetime object declare as decimal (38,0) not timestamp or date and the data input is 'yyyMMdd'.  How do I select data with that column convert as date format as 'yyyy-MM-dd' in spark sql (scala) within a day or two days old?

I have tried:

```
select count(*) from table_name where to_date('column_name','yyyy-MM-dd') = date_sub(current_date(),1));
```

this gives me 0 count when a data have quiet more than 500000 records

I tried:

```
select count(*) from table_name where from_unixtime(cast(load_dt_id as string), 'yyyy-MM-dd') = date_sub(current_date(), 1));
```

I got data in year 1970-01-31 which those year data are not in the table, even when I select that column where it's like '1970%', I got "OK" with bulk sign that accelerate query with Delta.  The data select in order of that column started with 20140320

Answer (score 2):

The format argument for to_date is the format of the **input**, not the desired output. Assuming you have yyyymmdd:

```
Seq(("20200208")).toDF("RawDate").select(col("RawDate"),to_date(col("RawDate"),"yyyyMMdd").as("formatted_date")).show()
+--------+--------------+
| RawDate|formatted_date|
+--------+--------------+
|20200208|    2020-02-08|
```

+--------+--------------+

Expanding this to filter by the derived date column:

```
val raw = Seq(("20200208"),("20200209"),("20200210")).toDF("RawDate")
raw: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [RawDate: string]

raw.select(col("RawDate"),to_date(col("RawDate"),"yyyyMMdd").as("formatted_date")).filter($"formatted_date".geq(date_add(current_date,-1))).show
+--------+--------------+
| RawDate|formatted_date|
+--------+--------------+
|20200209|    2020-02-09|
|20200210|    2020-02-10|
+--------+--------------+
```

Comment: yes, column is already in yyyymmdd.  
I have tried simple just select the column_name:

    select to_date(col("column_name"),"yyyyMMdd").as("formatted_date").show() from table_name;
I get mismatched input '"formatted_date"' error.  I'm new in scala sql and so sorry,. I don't understand how you want me to do here. If I want to pull the all the record from table, I need to put where clause with those syntax your provided for an output?  I tried the syntax your provided as select and it's not work.

Comment: See expanded answer.

Comment: FYI, i converted the out put from decimal to date successful but it didn't work in the where clause, compare with sysdate -1.

The syntax is:  select date_sub(to_date(cast(column_name as string),'yyyyMMdd') from table_name;